# How can I install Spyder and all its prerequisites in one click?

Tags: 12.04, debian-installer, spyder

There are like >50 debian packages to download and install if you do it manually.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Not one click, but cut and paste this into a terminal window:

```
sudo apt-get install spyder
```

Comment: I've tried that but it needs several things I don't have, that's why I asked how to install all the prerequisites too. It requires python 2.6 and I have python 2.7.3.

Comment: That's the beauty of debian package management - it installs the dependencies automatically.  It sounds like something is broken, can you past the results into your question please?

Comment: Yeah something was broken I fixed it, and now it works perfectly thanks!

Comment: I cannot launch spyder after installing it via apt-get. The spyder icon in the dash is not working at all. When I type `spyder` in terminal, I get the startup error message `ImportError: No module named rich_ipython_widget` . Did anyone encounter similar problems? I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and the (default) python version `2.7.6`

Answer (score 5):

Open "Ubuntu Software Center" search for spyder and click on "Install."